# How to show the inductive step of the strong induction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing, induction

**Note:** This problem is from Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications [7th ed, prob 2, pg 341].

**Problem:** Use strong induction to show that all dominoes fall in an infinite arrangement of dominoes if you know that the first three dominoes fall, that when a domino falls, the domino three farther down in the arrangement also falls

**My work:** I know that the inductive step in strong induction is to show that "if $p(i)$ is true for all $i$ less than or equal to $k$ then $p(k+1)$ is true".

I know that strong induction has the the same basis step so I showed that  the first domino will fall because of the stated "you know that the first three dominoes fall".

How would I describe the inductive step here?

What I tried was saying that I assume $p(k)$ is true for every $n \leq k$ or that every domino before $k$ and $k$ itself will fall. Then is $p(k+1)$ saying the next domino will fall? From  the infinite staircase idea, the rest of the dominoes will fall? Now I've shown that all dominoes will fall? Am I missing something?

Comment: You have now asked 74 questions and been a member for 6 months. It is time for you to learn how to [typeset your questions correctly](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @crash I've been using and learning MathJax. I didn't need to in this question.

Comment: How can you say that? What makes you think not using it in this question is appropriate?

Comment: Check my last question. There weren't any exponents, fractions, etc in this one.

Comment: That's completely irrelevant. You do not want to write p(k+1), for instance--this should be $p(k+1)$. Also, when possible, you do not want to include a screenshot of something--typeset it. It's just laziness to not type it up and expect someone else to come along and clean it up.

Comment: @crash Sorry was unaware. How do you typeset the image? Did a control find for typeset but didn't find anything.

Comment: You typeset the image by typing it all out. It's literally *that* simple.

Comment: @crash Alright done. Can you take back that downvote? Is this done just so somebody can copy and paste the question for reference?

Comment: OK. I just edited your post to show you what your questions from now on out *should* look like (please fill in the details in the section I grayed out). You generally show your work done on questions, and that is great, but you *must* (let me repeat, $\color{red}{\text{must}}$) typeset questions correctly if you are going to keep on using MSE frequently. Sometimes I don't even read posts when they are typeset horrendously. It's easy to avoid that problem by simply typesetting your questing correctly. Please do this from now on out.

Comment: @crash done. Thanks for all your advice :)

Comment: No problem. Your questions are exemplary in that they show a lot of work on your part--they just need to be typeset correctly. Patience and discipline! You'll learn all the typesetting stuff sooner than you think. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re missing most of the essential details, I’m afraid.

Let $P(k)$ be the assertion that domino $k$ falls. You’re given $P(1),P(2)$, and $P(3)$ to get the induction started. Now assume that for some $n\ge 3$ you know that $P(k)$ is true for each $k\le n$; that’s your induction hypothesis, and your task in the induction step is to prove $P(n+1)$.

You know that for each $k$, if $P(k)$ is true, then $P(k+3)$ is true as well. Let $$\ell=(n+1)-3=n-2\;;$$ since $n\ge 3$, $n-2\ge 1$, and therefore the truth of $P(\ell)$ is part of your induction hypothesis. Thus, $P(\ell+3)=P(n+1)$ is true, and the induction step is complete.

Comment: @committedandroider: It’s a fact that’s essential to the argument, since the induction hypothesis applies only to $k\le n$, but it’s so obvious that you probably don’t need to mention it explicitly even when you’re just learning the technique. Unless, of course, you’ve an instructor who is *very* fussy about the details — even fussier than I was.

Comment: Oh so basically the logic here is that since you have a domino that falls 3 before domino $n+1$, domino $n+1$ will fall? And you know that the domino that falls 3 before will fall because it is apart of your initial assumption?

Comment: @committedandroider: Yes, that’s exactly right.

Comment: Would the overall summary be "We have shown that if the first n dominoes fall, the (n+1) domino will fall as well because the domino that causes it to fall, (n-2) domino, lies in the first n dominoes. Therefore since the n+1 domino will fall, the rest of them will fall as well"?

Comment: @committedandroider: I don’t think that I’d put it quite like that. If I wanted to summarize the argument in outline, I’d say something like this: *We’re given that the first three dominoes fall, and we’ve shown that if $n\ge 3$ and the first $n$ dominoes fall, then so does the $(n+1$-st domino; it follows by the (strong) principle of mathematical induction that all of the dominoes fall.*

Comment: If we're given that the first four dominoes fall, would it be the same thing but with n>=4?

Comment: @committedandroider: That would give you the basis step for the situation in which whenever a domino falls, so does the domino *four* places further down the string. In that case you would indeed do the induction step for $n\get 4$.